# Alexa returns correct intent, but null slot value

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I've got a peculiar problem with my new Alexa skill.  The skill takes in a user input flavor, either "bitter", "spicy", "sweet", "dry", or "sour" as defined in the custom slots.  For whatever reason, when I test with "sweet" and "spicy", the response comes without a value attribute for the slot.  For example, querying the skill using the keyword "bitter" returns:

```
{
  "session": {
    "sessionId": "[masked]",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "[masked]"
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": "[masked]"
    },
    "new": true
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "[masked]",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "2016-11-07T03:48:53Z",
    "intent": {
      "name": "GetBerriesByFlavorIntent",
      "slots": {
        "flavor": {
          "name": "flavor",
          "value": "bitter"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Notice the flavor slot has an attribute "value", which is "bitter".  Now, when I call with "sweet" or "spicy", I get:

```
{
  "session": {
    "sessionId": "[masked]",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "[masked]"
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": "[masked]"
    },
    "new": true
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "[masked]",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "2016-11-07T03:50:54Z",
    "intent": {
      "name": "GetBerriesByFlavorIntent",
      "slots": {
        "flavor": {
          "name": "flavor"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this to happen?  I can verify that "dry" and "sour" also work, so it's really curious that these two particular keywords are having so much trouble.  I can also verify that Alexa is understanding the words correctly, as I am testing on the Alexa console and hard-coding the input values that are the same as the custom slot values.

[Full code](https://github.com/Shwheelz/PoffinDex/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Hum.  That is wierd.  And I guess it is consistent - bitter always works and sweet or spicy always don't work?  I would think that a null slot value means that it couldn't match any of the words in your list, but if you are testing in the console too then it can't be a word matching issue.  Are you sure you uploaded your word list correctly (no illegal chars)?

Comment: Did you define a sample utterance that includes the actual words sweet or spicy instead of the slot value?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem, but I'm unsure what caused it initially.  @Tom, originally I had the word list pipe separated instead of space separated.  I also had the slot values starting with an uppercase, whereas my json object had lowercase.  Neither of these seem to be the culprit though, as *some* of the words were working.  I also added semicolons to the speechOutput assignment.  Of those 3 things, something caused the skill to start working as expected. Perhaps it was something totally different though, maybe a weird caching quirk (I switched computers when it started working).

Comment: @MikeTaverne, no, that wasn't the issue.  Thanks for the input though!

Comment: With further testing, the issue is still popping up.  Still not sure what's causing it.  Alexa always figures out the right intent but no value is passed through.